# How to find common struct for all documents in collection?

Tags: arangodb

I have an array of documents, that have more or less same structure. But I need find fields that present in all documents. Somethink like:

```
{
  "name": "Jow",
  "salary": 7000,
  "age": 25,
  "city": "Mumbai"
},
{
  "name": "Mike",
  "backname": "Brown",
  "sex": "male",
  "city": "Minks",
  "age": 30
},
{
  "name": "Piter",
  "hobby": "footbol",
  "age": 25,
  "location": "USA"
},
{
  "name": "Maria",
  "age": 22,
  "city": "Paris"
},
```

All docs have `name` and `age`. How to find them with ArangoDB?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

- Retrieve the attribute names of each document
- Get the intersection of those attributes

i.e.

```
LET attrs = (FOR item IN test RETURN ATTRIBUTES(item, true))
RETURN APPLY("INTERSECTION", attrs)
```

`APPLY` is necessary so each list of attributes in `attrs` can be passed as a separate parameter to `INTERSECTION`.

Documentation:

- ATTRIBUTES: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#attributes
- INTERSECTION: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-array.html#intersection
- APPLY: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-miscellaneous.html#apply